# Why is the value of counter variable not changing on screen?

Tags: android, flutter

I added a floating action button and an increment function for increasing the value of counter variable, which is called in onressed function of floating button. The value changes on console but not on my app. Can you provide me with a solution to it?

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    int counter = 0;
   void incrementCounter() {
      counter++;
      print("You have pressed the button $counter times.");
    }
    return new Scaffold( 
       body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text("You have pressed the button $counter times.")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: new Icon(Icons.send),
      )
    );
   }
```

5th line is working on console but the 13th line is not working on my app, the counter is 0 only. I've added just enough code for you to understand it. ;)

Comment: chnage counter++; to setState(() => counter++);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are resetting the counter to `0` every time the widget is re-rendered and you don't use `setState()` to update the state so Flutter does not re-render when the value changes.

Change it to

```
int counter = 0;
void incrementCounter() {
  setState(() => counter++);
  print("You have pressed the button $counter times.");
}

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold( 
       body: new Center(
          child: new Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Text("You have pressed the button $counter times.")
            ],
          ),
        ),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: incrementCounter,
        child: new Icon(Icons.send),
      )
    );
   }
```

Comment: Error: The method 'setState' isn't defined for the class

Comment: This means the code is in a StatelessWidget. You can't have changing state in a StatelessWidget. Change it to a StatefulWidget.